# Count content items created by day

Tags: drupal, view

I need to create a view that would display a table that would show a count of items of content created on a particular day, like this:

```
Date       Items
2014-2-1   2
2014-2-2   3
2014-2-3   7
```

I created a view with aggregation, added a the following fields:

- "post date" with custom format Y-m-d and "Strip HTML tags" and "Remove whitespace" enabled in Rewrite Results section.
- "nid" with Aggregation type = Count

then I added a Sort Criteria on Post date with granularity set to "Day" and aggregation type  to "Group results together." Unfortunately, the results that I get are:

```
Date      Items
2014-2-1  1
2014-2-1  1
2014-2-2  1
2014-2-2  1
2014-2-2  1
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Group output by date maybe? Aggregation just does aggregation, doesn't add output grouping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the query your view is running actually looks like this:

```
SELECT node.created AS node_created, COUNT(node.nid) AS nid, DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND), '%Y%m%d') AS node_created_day
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('page')) ))
GROUP BY node_created, node_created_day
ORDER BY node_created_day DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It is grouping by the node_created field which is a timestamp.

You have 2 options:

1) Install the [Views Date Format SQL](https://drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module

2) Apply [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/844202#comment-5294936)

Both methods change the query so the date is actually formatted with MySQL, and then this value is used for the grouping.

The Views Date Format SQL module would change the query to look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(node.nid) AS nid, DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d') AS node_created, DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND), '%Y%m%d') AS node_created_day
FROM 
node node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('page')) ))
GROUP BY node_created, node_created_day
ORDER BY node_created_day DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This has the same effect as Mike's solution - *but* requires another module, so I would go with Mikes answer on this one...

Comment: Your right, I copied the wrong query (now updated). I also wasn't aware of your method. I think it is sounds like the best method as doesn't require a separate module or patch. (But you'd never guess that if you didn't know!)

Comment: I deleted my comment when I saw you'd updated your answer. I'm not 100% sure what the Views module is doing for my fix to work so perhaps it's the best for now, but one to watch in case things change with future updates to the Views module.

Comment: @MikeBroughton among 2 answers which version would work if view (of entity type users) needs to display total reg vs total login data.  

ex:  
period - tot registrations - tot logins  
jan-2017 - 17 - 12  
feb-2017 - 10 - 18

Comment: @kiranking I'm afraid I can't help. I haven't worked with Drupal for a few years now. At the time, I enabled MySQL query logging and used trial and error on the View options to get what I wanted. Sorry, I can't offer anything more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this used to work for the version I had. However it appears this isn't the case for some people so I'll leave it in case it is helpful to someone, but the other answers are probably better.

If you add the 'Minimum' aggregate function to your 'post date' ensuring you keep the granularity settings on your sort criteria, you'll get the results you want.

Adding the 'Minimum' aggregate function alters how the generated SQL query groups the results. Here is the before and after:

```
SELECT node.created AS node_created, COUNT(node.nid) AS nid, DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0   SECOND), '%Y%m%d') AS node_created_day
FROM 
node node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('dummyNode')) ))
GROUP BY node_created, node_created_day
ORDER BY node_created_day DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

vs

SELECT COUNT(node.nid) AS nid, MIN(node.created) AS node_created, DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0  SECOND), '%Y%m%d') AS node_created_day
FROM 
node node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('dummyNode')) ))
GROUP BY node_created_day
ORDER BY node_created_day DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

You can see the 'GROUP BY node_created' is removed.